# How Do I Turn This Into A Python List Comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'd like to make this more efficient but I can't figure out how to turn this into a python list comprehension.

```
coupons = []
for source in sources:
    for coupon in source:
        if coupon.code_used not in coupons:
            coupons.append(coupon.code_used)
```

Comment: You cannot do list comprehension if you need to reference the list you are creating as it is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access the list you currently creating, but if the order is not important you can use a `set`:

```
coupons = set(coupon.code_used for source in sources for coupon in source)
```

Comment: Though it will not restore ordering, you could wrap the `set(...)` in a `list(...)` command to get back to the `list` type he was originally creating if maintaining that type is at all important for future use.

Answer (score 2):

```
used_codes = set(coupon.code_used for source in sources for coupon in source)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the order of the resulting list is unimportant, because then we can just use a set to eliminate duplicates.

```
coupons = list(set(coupon.code_used for source in sources for coupon in source))
```

This uses a generator expression, with the `for` clauses appearing in the same order as in the nested loop, to extract all the codes. The `set` keeps only unique codes, and `list` creates a list (arbitrarily ordered) from the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
coupons = {x for x in (y.code_used for y in coupon for coupon in sources)}
```

you are actually looking for a `set`